# How do I get the Asset's file path in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
  assets:
    - assets/mySecertImage.png
```

Here is how I read back the assets:

```
  var data = await PlatformAssetBundle().load('assets/mySecertImage.png');
```

Instead of reading it directly, can I get the file path instead? If it is not possible to do so, it is possible to change the `data` to become a `File` object? Thanks.

Comment: Would it solve your problem reading from the bundle and saving it to a real file when starting the app (in the main method)? If so let me know and I'll show you the code to do just that.

Comment: This code will work perfectly
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
  final buffer = byteData.buffer;
  Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  String tempPath = tempDir.path;
  var filePath =
      tempPath + '/file_01.tmp'; // file_01.tmp is dump file, can be anything
  return File(filePath)
      .writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
}

Answer (score 28):

Have you found a solution ? (I am looking for the same as well).

Here is a workaround that I pursue (out of lack of a better idea)... :

I do:

- create a new File-path to your Documents-directory
  (named app.txt in the below code-example)
- copy the File sitting in your assets folder to this
  Documents-directory location
- work with the copied file from now on (where you now have File-path and even Byte-content if needed)

Here is the Dart-code:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';

Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var dbPath = join(directory.path, "app.txt");
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/demo.txt");
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

Some people also work with the `getDatabasesPath()` instead of `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`. But I figured that on an iOS-Simulator this ends up being the exact same location. (not verified on Android)... So, it would say:

```
var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
var dbPath = join(dbDir, "app.txt");
ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/demo.txt");
List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

For an iOS-Simulator: In both above examples, you can find your copied file under the folder:

`/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AE5C3275-CD65-3537-9B32-53533B97477C/data/Containers/Data/Application/7BE2B2EE-4E45-3783-B4BD-341DA83C43BD/Documents/app.txt`

(of course, the UUID's being different in your case...)

And if you want to copy the file only if it does not exist already, you could write:

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var dbPath = join(directory.path, "app.txt");
if (FileSystemEntity.typeSync(dbPath) == FileSystemEntityType.notFound) {
  ByteData data = await rootBundle.load("assets/demo.txt");
  List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
  await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What is 'rootBundle' then?

Comment: @OliverDixon rootBundle is a Flutter library.

import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

See here for more info : https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Comment: please don't forget to add first the dependency `path_provider: ^1.3.0` to `pubspec.yaml` other the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` will give you error.

Answer (score 11):

You can not get the file path of an asset file, because assets, that are bundled with your app, are stored inside an archive.

See the "Asset building" section here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling

> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called
> the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue but fixed by calling this.

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
 final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
 final buffer = byteData.buffer;
 Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
 String tempPath = tempDir.path;
 var filePath =
  tempPath + '/file_01.tmp'; // file_01.tmp is dump file, can be anything
 return File(filePath)
  .writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, 
 byteData.lengthInBytes));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to Harjinder's implementation:
It handles the case that the path includes directories and it avoids rewriting the file

```
  Future<File> _getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    String tempPath = tempDir.path;
    var filePath = "$tempPath/$path";
    var file = File(filePath);
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      return file;
    } else {
      final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
      final buffer = byteData.buffer;
      await file.create(recursive: true);
      return file
          .writeAsBytes(buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes,
          byteData.lengthInBytes));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure sometimes is required to specify the path as following: 'packages/$nameOfThePackage/$assetPath' if your assets are in a separate package you might use for splitting the features.
nameOfThePackage being the library name of the alternative package you use.
assetPath as an example is 'assets/images/'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).