# Flutter execute binary

Tags: dart, flutter

How to execute binary file in flutter? I have put the binary into assets and added to my code function to 'unpack' it ([How do I get the Asset's file path in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353764/how-do-i-get-the-assets-file-path-in-flutter)).

The file is in the app data folder:

```
generic_x86:/data/data/com.example.hidden/app_flutter # ls
binaryfile flutter_assets 
generic_x86:/data/data/com.example.hidden/app_flutter #
```

However when I try executing it using the `Process.run` it says `Permission denied`. When I `chmod +x` or `chmod 777` it using root shell, it says `No such file or directory`. However I would prefer some no root method to do this.

How can I properly execute prebuilt binaries in Flutter? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Any progress in here?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to do this is to copy your binary file from assets to a local directory, as obtained by `final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, and to then call `Process.run` with that file as the command argument.

Even then, I don't believe you can run anything as `root` this way, and your access to the file system may be quite limited.