# Flutter : Convert jpg to webp

Tags: image, flutter, dart, image-compression, webp

I want to convert .jpg or .png files to .webp. Unfortunately image package [only support webp reading](https://pub.dev/packages/image) and not writing.

One solution would be to add the linux binary file to flutter (cwebp), but how to execute it smoothly ? I checked and found that this question was [asked over 1 year ago and still unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774550/flutter-execute-binary)

I am open to any suggestion, the end goal is not so much the format in itself but the lowest file size for overall good quality on mobile phone resolution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flutter has a compressor package, called `flutter_image_compress`. It has a compressor for web images.

```dart
Future<Uint8List> testComporessList(Uint8List list) async {
    final result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
      list,
      minHeight: 1080,
      minWidth: 1080,
      quality: 96,
      rotate: 270,
      format: CompressFormat.webp,
    );
    print(list.length);
    print(result.length);
    return result;
  }
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

Comment: Does it support animated webp? like convert gif to animated webp. I read on it's doc that it only read webp file while read+write gif