# How to embed external exe files in a Flutter project for Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

In my Flutter project for Windows, I want to run some `.exe` files that I want to embed in my project, instead of copying/pasting them by hand in the correct location.

So I tried to add the `.exe` files in my `assets` folder, like the following:

```
assets
  \exe
  \images
```

and add the `exe` folder in my `pubspec.yaml` file like the following:

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/exe/
```

The good news is: the exe files are copied in the correct location when I build my project.
The bad news is: I don't know how to get the absolute path of my `exe` folder in Dart.

So, is there a way to get the absolute path of the `exe` folder for a Windows project, or is there another way to embed my `.exe` files so I can get their paths and run them (using `Process.start()`)?

Thanks.

Comment: facing the same problem did you find any solution ??

Comment: @AtulChaudhary My answer below

Comment: Here is a possible answer (spoiler: you can't get the file path): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63995005/5517547

Comment: I faced the same problem, and my workaround was to include the exe file inside the installer (not inside the project). In my case I used Msix installer for Flutter

Comment: @gowthamanC My answer below

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I did to get the absolute path of the `exe` folder (only tested on Windows) :

```
// returns the abolute path of the executable file of your app:
String mainPath = Platform.resolvedExecutable;

// remove from that path the name of the executable file of your app:
mainPath = mainPath.substring(0, mainPath.lastIndexOf("\\"));

// concat the path with '\data\flutter_assets\assets\exe', where 'exe' is the
// directory where are the executable files you want to run from your app:
Directory directoryExe = Directory("$mainPath\\data\\flutter_assets\\assets\\exe")
```

Comment: I've a problem with this solution in Linux (I assume that in Windows could be similar): when you try to start the process of your exe file, it throws a "permission denied" exception

Comment: @PabloInsua try this, chmod a+x yourfile